# How to get heap size on windows Platform

Tags: c++, windows

As the question title indicates I want to know if there is a way to get heap size of the current process.

Comment: Because of how heaps work, the heap size is not typically useful information.  Are you possibly asking how to know *the largest heap allocation that can be made*?

Comment: No, what I want to know is the Used Heap Size

Comment: In addition to what @DrewDormann said, your question is very vague. Do you want the heap size for the system as a whole (there's really no such thing) or for a particular process (which can have multiple heaps - one for each thread)? Why is this information necessary?

Comment: I already mentioned that it's for the current process

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this - but I think it will be slow and painful.

1. Use [GetProcessHeaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee175820%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to enumerate through the process heaps.
2. Use [HeapWalk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee175819%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to enumerate through the blocks in each heap.
3. Use [HeapSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366706%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get sizes and type of different blocks

Comment: @NikBougalis - local variables are created on the stack and not on the heap?

Comment: D'oh! Too early in the morning and not enough coffee. Silly comment deleted.

Comment: There is no need to use HeapSize, as PROCESS_HEAP_ENTRY already contains all size information.